# jquery show loading in <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a jquery function that retrieves data from a php file and puts all that into a select list, which works just fine, the problem is that it takes some time to load and i wanted to show a loading text in the select while its loading, however it doesn't seem to work, here's what i've tried:

```
var modelSelect = $('[name="model"]'); // this is the select <select> list 

$('[name="make"]').on('change', function(){ // another <select> that fires up the ajax 
var chosen = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {'send': chosen},
        beforeSend: function(){
            modelSelect.html("loading"); //doesn't work
                },
        success: function(data){
            modelSelect.html(data);


        }

    });

});
```

any ideas how i can make it say loading there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code instead

```
modelSelect.html("<option> loading ... </option>");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: be Welcome! Don't forget to accept answer to help other finding the solution.